# Serialized PHP array in Flickr

Tags: php, flickr, serialization

I have this serialized array but I have no idea how to get the id: 7796249@N02

```
a:2:{s:4:"user";a:3:{s:2:"id";s:11:"7796249@N02";s:4:"nsid";s:11:"7796249@N02";s:8:"username";a:1:{s:8:"_content";s:9:"ilhan.z.y";}}s:4:"stat";s:2:"ok";}


$array = unserialize('a:2:{s:4:"user";a:3:{s:2:"id";s:11:"7796249@N02";s:4:"nsid";s:11:"7796249@N02";s:8:"username";a:1:{s:8:"_content";s:9:"ilhan.z.y";}}s:4:"stat";s:2:"ok";}');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's where the id is:

```
$array['user']['id'];
```

Next time, use [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
var_dump($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

to see a human-readable representation of the array.